# want to add one more column in my Sql server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

i am using this query to get some result

```
select t.accode,t.acname, sum(t.debit)as debit, sum(t.credit) as credit from transactions t 
inner join accounts a on a.code = t.accode 
where a.TypeCode = 5 and t.date between '2014-05-01' and '2014-05-15' 
group by t.accode,t.acname
```

i am getting this result with this query

```
accode   acname    debit    credit
1         umer      200      300
```

now i want to add a previos balance column in this result. sample query for that is

```
sum(debit)-sum(credit) as previousbalance from transaction where date < '2014-05-01'
```

and then the result will look like this

```
accode   acname  previousbalance  debit    credit
1         umer      50             200      300
```

can any one please tell me how to do this ? i shall be very thankful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert a subquery in the `SELECT` statement like this:

```
select t.accode,t.acname, sum(t.debit)as debit, sum(t.credit) as credit 
, (SELECT sum(t2.debit) - sum(t2.credit) FROM transactions AS t2 INNER JOIN accounts AS a2 ON t2.accode = a2.code 
    WHERE a2.code = t.accode AND t2.date < '2014-05-01') as prevbalance
from transactions t 
inner join accounts a on a.code = t.accode 
where a.TypeCode = 5 and t.date between '2014-05-01' and '2014-05-15' 
group by t.accode,t.acname
```

You might need another group by in that subquery, not sure about that.

Comment: Please be more elaborate when commenting, I don't know what you mean exactly.

Comment: And have you tried adding a group by (on t2.accode for instance) in the subquery?

Comment: good job man just change a2.code = t.accode in sub query. do it so i can accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the columns to your existing field as below:

```
select t.accode,t.acname, sum(t.debit)as debit, sum(t.credit) as credit,
( sum(t.debit) - sum(t.credit) ) as previousbalance 
 from transactions t 
inner join accounts a on a.code = t.accode 
where a.TypeCode = 5 and t.date between '2014-05-01' and '2014-05-15' 
group by t.accode,t.acname;
```

Another approach would be inner/nested queries:

```
select tab.*, (credit-debit) as previousbalance 
from
(
   select t.accode,t.acname, sum(t.debit)as debit, sum(t.credit) as credit from transactions t 
   inner join accounts a on a.code = t.accode 
   where a.TypeCode = 5 and t.date between '2014-05-01' and '2014-05-15' 
   group by t.accode,t.acname
) tab;
```

Comment: This will not give the desired results as the OP wants different conditions for debit/credit and previousbalance

Comment: i want previous balance before that date.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a `CROSS APPLY` here

```
SELECT t.accode, t.acname, pb.previousbalance
     , SUM(t.debit) as debit, SUM(t.credit) as credit
FROM   transactions t 
       INNER JOIN accounts a on a.code = t.accode
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUM(debit) - SUM(credit) as previousbalance
                    FROM   transaction t1
                    WHERE  date < '2014-05-01'
                      AND  t.accode = t1.accode
                    GROUP BY t1.accode, t1.acname) pb
WHERE  a.TypeCode = 5 
  AND t.date BETWEEN '2014-05-01' AND '2014-05-15' 
GROUP BY t.accode, t.acname
```

but without some test data I cannot be sure

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to test on, but this should work. However, isn't there a cutoff date where you don't want to look back further?

```
select t.accode, t.acname, 
       sum( case when t.date < '2014-05-01' then t.debit - t.credit end ) as PrevBal,
       sum( case when between '2014-05-01' and '2014-05-15' then t.debit end ) as Debit,
       sum( case when between '2014-05-01' and '2014-05-15' then t.credit end ) as Credit
from   transactions t 
join   accounts a
  on   a.code = t.accode 
where  a.TypeCode = 5
--  and  t.date >= :CutoffDate
group by t.accode, t.acname;
```